# Ternary operator in lambda expression C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to put a conditional expression with in a lambda query as below

```
GetPeers(bool? isConnected = true)
{
    dbContext
    .peers
    .Where(m => isConnected.HasValue ? m.IsConnected == isConnected.Value : true)
    .ToList();
}
```

Above statement gives me `Nullable object must have a value.` exception.

I dont get it! What is wrong in my query?

What I want if `isConnected` is null, then it should be returning all the records otherwise on the basis of `m.IsConnected == isConnected.Value`,

Comment: Based on what little context you've provided, I can only guess that the property referred to by `m.IsConnected` is of type `Nullable<bool>` and that it does not have a value. However, it's also possible that either `dbContext` or `dbContext.peers` is also null.

Comment: What is the data type of "m"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with how Entity Framework is translating the ternary expression, it is attempting to create a SQL parameter using the result of `isConnected.Value` but `isConnected` is null so it throws.

My preferred option is to only apply the predicate if there is actually a predicate to apply:

```
IQueryable<Peer> peers = dbContext.peers;
if(isConnected.HasValue)
{
    var isConnectedValue = isConnected.Value;
    peers = peers.Where(m => m.IsConnected == isConnectedValue);
}
return peers.ToList();
```

Comment: Could you please add necessary tags on the question so it is clear why this answer (looking very appropriate) applies? (Possibly consider adding editing question).

Answer (score 3):

You can change this

```
m.IsConnected == isConnected.Value
```

to this

```
m.IsConnected == (isConnected.HasValue && isConnected.Value)
```

The problem is that `isConnected` doesn't have always a value. It's a `bool?`. So it can has a value or not (`null`). If it has a value, it would be either true/false. The problem arises, when it has no value. This is happening due to conditional operator. According to the documentation:

> The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on
>   the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the
>   conditional operator.
>
> condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
>
> **Either** the type of first_expression and second_expression **must be the**
>   **same**, **or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other**.

For the full documentation, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Comment: or even `m.IsConnected == isConnected.GetValueOrDefault(true)`

Comment: Not sure it *explains* the problem - `isConnected.HasValue ?` - so `isConnected` *always* has value on right side of `:`

Comment: @CodeCaster not based on OP's question - he/she is returning `true` from the "else" side of the ternary operator.

Comment: Hi @BrianDriscoll, thanks for your answer, But in your query `m.IsConnected == isConnected.HasValue && isConnected.Value`, If  `isConnected` is null, then it would be `m.IsConnected == false`. But what I want is if  `isConnected` is null, then it should be returning all the records otherwise `m.IsConnected == isConnected.Value`, So I wrote `: true` at tail of it.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense, it completely changes the conditional logic and makes it possible to call `.Value` when `.HasValue` is false which would throw, how's this got so many upvotes??

Comment: @Lukazoid why it changes the conditional logic? You simply can't use `m.IsConnected == isConnected.Value`. The compiler doesn't know, if there is any value. Hence, you have to use short circuit logic.

Comment: If `isConnected = null` and `m.IsConnected = false` then your solution will call `isConnected.Value` which will throw. The OP is using the conditional operator correctly and only accessing `.Value` when `.HasValue == true`, the only issue is how EF is translating it to SQL.

Comment: Let's take this `m.IsConnected == isConnected.HasValue && isConnected.Value`. If `isConnected` is null, then `isConnected.HasValue` is false. So if `m.IsConnected` is false, the above expression evaluates to true. I don't see any call to the `isConnected.Value`. When you have `a && b`, where `a` and `b` are expressions. If the first expression, `a`, is evaluated to false, then the `b` wouldn't be evaluated. The result of `a&&b` would be false. This is called short circuit logic evaluation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx.

Comment: If `m.IsConnected` is false and `isConnected.HasValue` is false, then we have `false == false && isConnected.Value` which becomes `true && isConnected.Value`, which will evaluate `isConnected.Value`, I understand how short circuiting works, in your given example it will evaluate the second operand which would throw.

Comment: I think that this operator `&&` has greater precedence than this `==`. If am wrong, please correct me. That being said, this  `isConnected.HasValue && isConnected.Value` would be evaluated first and the the `==`.

Comment: `==` has a higher precedence than `&&`, see [Operator precedence and associativity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @Lukazoid my bad :( Thanks. I just corrected correspondingly my answer.

Comment: No problem @Christos, we are always learning, your answer still isn't logically what the OP was after however, now if `isConnected` is `null` it only returns results where `m.IsConnected == false`, the OP wants all results returned when `isConnected` is `null`.